# Understanding the limitations of HTML5 local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

We are in the process of moving an application we currently have built in Excel over to HTML5/JS. One of the strengths of existing architecture is that much of the data (8 tables, ~8 columns per table, ~200 rows per table) that we use is currently collected on startup and then used locally. This provides us with an "always on" extremely fast user experience. As we look to make the transition to a browser based platform (strongly considering a Chrome packaged app) we're hoping to maintain this type of data availability. My question is this: is it feasible to carry out this same type of local data storage using HTML5 local.storage (or possibly chrome.storage) in a similar manner?

Comment: Read before [`DOM Storage guide`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

Comment: local storage size limit: https://arty.name/localstorage.html

Comment: I suggest to you consider about [IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb) instead of LocasStorage.

Comment: +1 @PeterJurkovič 's comment. Plus, I think [localForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) would help you.